# Why the imperfection?

Tags: allah

السلام عليكم

I have been wondering about it for quite some time now. Now, before I further explain my question please bear in mind that I am neither a better human being nor a better Muslim then many of you, so please bear with me.

My question is why did Allah created everything with an evolutionary nature?

Why did He not bless us with Islam in the first place? Why did this completion take so many 
years? I am talking about all the religions that were there before Islam.

Why did He not reveal our beloved Prophet (PBUH) upon us when He Himself say that The Prophet was the first one to be created (Please feel free to correct if I’m wrong)?

Why did He not create all the humans perfect? Why not make this world heaven?

Why didn't He make this world PERFECT?

And I have no doubt HE could have done all of the above as HE wished, I just want to know WHY NOT?

Thanks and may Allah bless you all.

Comment: Too many questions in-one doesn't fit the StackExchange model very well.

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you take a look at our [help-center](http://islam.stackexchange.com/helpcenter).  As it currently stands, you are asking too many questions in one, we suggest you split them into individual questions, thank you :)

Comment: I agree that please don't ask too many question in one go. Here is a question [very related](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5996/what-purposes-are-served-by-the-afterlife-and-the-world-to-come-that-cannot-be-s/8386#8386)

Comment: Why didn't He make this world perfect? Why not make this world heaven? Because not all people are worthy of heaven. How does He know who is worthy who is not? By sending us to this world, which is like an entrance exam for the Hereafter, where you are supposed to be tested here. My interpretation. Allah knows the best.

Comment: @mezhang Yes you are right and i was wrong to ask. Allah knows the best.

Comment: @hussain There is nothing wrong in asking. These are the questions I asked myself as well. We are all ignorant and Allah blesses us with wisdom.

Comment: @hussain, please correct me if I am wrong, but I think your question boils down to 1 simple point. How can (or why would) perfection (god) even think low enough to create imperfection (humans)?  Shouldn't a perfect entity only want to think perfect thoughts, therefore, only want to create further perfection?

Comment: These are the type of questions which generally comes in evry one's heart, so your question is nice and i appreciate it,but i m sure there is some perfect answer of this question. Becuase whater is done by allah , is done well with the valid and right reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Islam was the religion in the first place, it was the religion of Adam, and the message that came to all and every Prophet (peace be upon them) before Muhammad.  But the messages of the previous Prophets, although identical theology-wise to what Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him) brought, had differences in it's practices because what those Prophets brought was for a specific time and a specific place and for a specific people, and when it gets corrupted through time another messenger is sent.  But when Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him) came, no other Prophet will come after him, and the message he brought was for all times, places, and people until the standing of the hour.  Furthermore even when Muhammad came, and Islam was set and perfected in one second, what would have been the point?  and how fast do you think people can change? can they change overnight?

Furthermore, Muhammad (peace and blessings be upon him) was not the first one to be created.

### Why did He not create all the humans perfect? Why not make this world heaven? Why did He not create all the humans perfect? Why not make this world heaven?

Firstly Allah created us humans in the best of forms, and has given us a great responsibility.  But even so, non of us are perfect in every way, and Allah is the only one perfect in every way.  Secondly we are put in this world to be tested and tried, and for us to be differentiated from those who are bad and those who do good.  If Allah were to have made this world heaven, then what would be the point of this world and the point of striving to get to heaven in the hereafter?

### Why didn't He make this world perfect?

You are simply asking for too much of this life.  This Dunya is transitional, it will all end, while the hereafter is eternal and far better then this world.  And lastly, yes Allah could do anything if He wants to, but that is just it, He does what He wills and we are asked about our actions while He is not questioned, and Allah is all knowledgeable and all Wise.  May He forgive me of my shortcomings, and may He guide us all.

Comment: Maybe you can mention that Adam and Eve were residing in paradise until the jin led them astray to this world?

Comment: I guess you put it best as any human could. Maybe i was asking too much. Only thing that prompted me to ask this question was curiosity and maybe i was even wrong to ask such a question since what goes in Allah's mind is beyond our thinking capabilities.

Comment: and who am i to ask why He creates the way He did and still does and always will. and as you said it already He does what He wills and we are asked about our actions while He is not questioned, and Allah is all knowledgeable and all Wise. May He forgive me of my shortcomings, and may He guide us all. Amen!

Answer (score 0):

First, simply because Allah the Just never choose what to create and what not to create. He creates everything that is creatable and the causes for its existence are complete (the Causality).

Next, simply because we are human beings and Jinns are Jinns. If Allah wanted to create you at the "target stage determined for you" since the beginning of your creation (that is, if you were creatable such) then you may have been probably created as an angle, not a human being any more. There were creatable entities in His knowledge that can improve, so He created Human and Jinns who can improve, so they should be given the opportunity to improve, so Dunya was created for this sake, then depending on how much they have improved in Dunya they will be given different life styles in the Hereafter that will last eternally. For those who have reached the top stages (according to what was determined for them, comparison is between one and him/her self, not between different persons) a perfect life is considered in Heaven.

*Note. I'm not a scholar, so be careful of using the info provided above.*

Answer (score -1):

Allah is perfect and has made everything perfect. All the worlds including Earth and the humans on it are perfect. Everything happens according To His Will.

Why? Because he loves us.

According to hadith:(All is well with the believers under all circumstances"
It reminds us that in the divine Knowledge All is well, all is complete)

But you have to see it that way. It is about perception. It is a spiritual thing. You have to have faith for your own good.

Abu Yahya Suhaib bin Sinan (May Allah be pleased with him) reported that:

The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "How wonderful is the case of a believer; there is good for him in everything and this applies only to a believer. If prosperity attends him, he expresses gratitude to Allah and that is good for him; and if adversity befalls him, he endures it patiently and that is better for him".

I am going to try to explain it.

For example, if a person had been healthy instead of having to stay home and rest, that person might have been run over by a car and killed.  So who is to say that being perfectly healthy is better?  In fact, perhaps one’s illness or other disability has somehow kept you alive. ( source: http://drlwilson.com/articles/PERFECT.htm) I just used the example.

Another example:

Maulana Jalaluddeen Rumi (Rahmatullah ’alaih) narrates a story in
his Mathnavi; an incident which occurred during the time of
Rasulullah e: Once, after having performed wudhu, Rasulullah e
was about to wear his leather sock when an eagle came along,
snatched it and flew away. Nabi e was most distressed as he was
preparing for Salaah.
In a short while, the eagle returned and turned the sock upside down,
towards the ground, causing a snake that was inside, to fall out.
The eagle then presented the sock to Rasulullah e and addressed him
: “O Rasulullah e ! The reason for me having taken the sock was that
there was a snake hidden inside it. Otherwise I would never harm you,
for Allah Ta’ala has ordered me to protect you. It was on account of
the snake that I flew off with the sock.”

So for a believer everything is *always* for his own good.

Answer this question as Einstein said (but smart he didn't answer it you have to answer it for yourself) Is the Universe Friendly? Replace Universe with Allah

If you say no then you will see this world as hostile and see behind every human and three enemy and this will cause you stress and anger and enmity. This will effect your thinking, behavior toward others.

But if you say yes then you will see friends everywhere. Remember God has provided the sun for you, the air the trees and the people to help you develop spiritually learn lessen and test. If you become ill and you Thank Allah for the illness because you know it is for your own will( may be you have to learn something or experience something whatever the reason is it is good)

Another example. If you have a cut and you say stop the bleeding I don't want to bleed because it is bad and evil. Then how will you be healed? The blood comes and becomes hard so that a new skin develops and then when the skin is developed you scratch the hard blood of because it itches and voila! you got a new skin.

If you go to a doctor and he gives you an injection(vaccine) to heal. But if you say No I don't want an injection the doctor is evil he wants to hurt me then how will you be healed. So you have to ACCEPT the injection and TRUST the doctor in order to be healed

**TRUST = TAWAKKUL and ACCEPT= DESTINY**(Always for your own good)

But you will not always understand or see the reason because you are not God. But thorugh Divines Eye everything is perfect. You just have to see it that way.

And if you see that God is always is with you and *never* leaves you. (In your everyday lives and experiences) then you will be automatic grateful and praise with your heart Allah! I felt that way when I saw it that way I felt whole, connected to the world and protected everywhere even dark in the night in the woods if I wanted to go there.

The consequence is that your thinking (VERY IMPORTANT!) and your behavior towards other will be friendly, because you know that Allah helped you so much!) Even when someone hurts you.  You will Thank Allah for this hurt because it is for a good reason for you but you don't know And maybe you can give love back to that person( for example thank him) This way you will not feel hate or want to hurt them back!

Another consequence is that you don't become cynical(VERY IMPORTANT!) to this world and stay uplifted and happy.

Another consequence is that your heart will feel at peace. You know that you are at the perfect place and the perfect time and your feelings are perfect at the moment. Then you will not doubt yourself and and love yourself. But in a humble way. Every mistake that you made unintentionally(sometimes intentionally)  you know it is Divine will, so it is perfect. You will not feel hatred to yourself

What is good what is evil? All is perfect!(praise to Allah) An accident is perfect death is perfect maybe if someone lived longer he wold indulge in sins. (Allah knows) (don't say this cynical but really try to see it that way with love)

Satan works for Allah for your own sake. If you have Tawakkul he will go away!

But don't think I am perfect, because you are not. (if you understand what I mean)

Remember live is about *love* (Allah loves you so much that you don't even know that).

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. Please consider properly formatting the answer to improve it's readability by [edit]ing it. Also get rid of statement that are nere rhetorics (e.g. * if you understand what I mean*) and be objective.

Comment: @Anonymous, so when a baby is made to suffer by a sick twisted father because he rapes her, that is considered  perfection? "and has made everything perfect"?  I fail to see the perfection in the suffering, such a child would have to go through...